# Use row_number() in BigQuery in CTE

Tags: google-bigquery, window-functions, row-number

I'm trying to include row numbers per orderId with this query but I get a error message saying "Unrecognized name: BQ" when selecting the columns in the subquery. I havn't used it too much so not sure where I'm doing it wrong. Can anyone see it?

```
     WITH BQ AS(
        SELECT 
        (SELECT customDimensions.value FROM UNNEST(t.customDimensions)
        AS customDimensions WHERE customDimensions.index = 6) as
        orderId_bq, 
        hits.eventinfo.eventaction as event_action, 
        hits.transaction.transactionId as trx_id, 
        hits.page.pagePath as page, 
        hitnumber AS hitnumber 
    
    FROM `xxxxx-xxxx.xxxxxx.ga_sessions_20210801` t,
    
    UNNEST(HITS) as hits 
    WHERE (SELECT customDimensions.value FROM UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS customDimensions WHERE customDimensions.index = 8) = 'se'
    AND (SELECT customDimensions.value FROM UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS customDimensions WHERE customDimensions.index = 4) = 'soffadirekt'
    --AND hits.eventinfo.eventaction IN ('complete purchase')
    --AND hits.transaction.transactionId IS NULL
    --and hits.page.pagePath != '/backend-transaction'
    --and hits.eventinfo.eventaction != 'backend transaction' )
    
    )
       
    SELECT 
    BQ.event_action,
    BQ.trx_id,
    BQ.page,
    BQ.hitnumber,
    
    FROM (SELECT Row_number()
            OVER( PARTITION BY BQ.orderId_bq
            ORDER BY BQ.hitnumber) as RN,
            BQ.orderId_bq
    
    from BQ
)
```

I did also try this but then it doesn't regognize 'flat.orderId' instead:

```
WITH BQ AS

(SELECT 
(SELECT customDimensions.value FROM UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS customDimensions WHERE customDimensions.index = 6) as orderId_bq,
hits.eventinfo.eventaction as event_action,
hits.transaction.transactionId as trx_id,
hits.page.pagePath as page,
hitnumber AS hitnumber 

FROM `xxxx-xxxxxxxx.ga_sessions_20210801` t,
UNNEST(HITS) as hits 
WHERE (SELECT customDimensions.value FROM UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS customDimensions WHERE customDimensions.index = 8) = 'se'
AND (SELECT customDimensions.value FROM UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS customDimensions WHERE customDimensions.index = 4) = 'soffadirekt'

),

flat AS (
SELECT 
*
from bq
)

SELECT 
flat.orderId_bq,
flat.event_action,
flat.trx_id,
flat.page,
flat.hitnumber, 
FROM (SELECT Row_number()
        OVER( PARTITION BY flat.orderId_bq
        ORDER BY flat.hitnumber) as RN,

flat.orderId_bq,
flat.event_action,
flat.trx_id,
flat.page,
flat.hitnumber 

FROM flat
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error `Unrecognized name: BQ` happens because your are trying to query `BQ.*` that does not exist since you did not add the `BQ` alias on your subquery. Adding `AS BQ` should work. See query:

```
SELECT 
BQ.event_action,
BQ.trx_id,
BQ.page,
BQ.hitnumber,

FROM (SELECT Row_number()
        OVER( PARTITION BY BQ.orderId_bq
        ORDER BY BQ.hitnumber) as RN,
        BQ.orderId_bq
        FROM BQ) AS BQ
```

Just a suggestion, it might be better to use a different alias so your query will be much readable.

I tested this using a table of mine where I add `AS subq1` at my subquery. See a simple test:

```
WITH subq1 AS (SELECT amount_paid,customer from `my-project.test_dataset.myTable`)

SELECT
  subq1.RN,
  subq1.customer,
  subq1.amount_paid
FROM
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER(ORDER BY subq1.amount_paid) as RN,
    subq1.customer,
    subq1.amount_paid 
    FROM subq1) AS subq1
  LIMIT 3
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I did the same as you did but it tells me that the name 'event_action' can't be found inside BQ. 


I added BQ.* instead of BQ.event_action but then I only got a table with the row number and order id's. 


I think I'm thinking about the syntax for CTE's in the wrong way or something. I'm more used to Microsoft SQL. It seems you have your subquery within your CTE (your with clause) - right?

Comment: Btw, this worked - for some reason it didn't complain about the name of the subquery this time. But can I ask why you have to select the columns from the first table twice when doing a row_number function? Both before and after the function? Is it some kind of partitioning happening? (See my own answer to the question to see the query that worked)

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, to be honest I used a very small table (2 columns only) I selected columns twice just to reproduce your issue and provide a fix. But either way it might not be a good example, I'll try to use another table for the example.

Answer (score 1):

Query that worked:

```
WITH raw AS 

(SELECT 
(SELECT customDimensions.value FROM UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS customDimensions WHERE customDimensions.index = 6) as orderId_bq, 
    hits.eventinfo.eventaction as event_action, 
    hits.transaction.transactionId as trx_id, 
    hits.page.pagePath as page, 
    hitnumber AS hitnumber 

FROM `xxx-xxx.xxxxxx.ga_sessions_*` t,
UNNEST(HITS) as hits 
WHERE (SELECT customDimensions.value FROM UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS customDimensions WHERE customDimensions.index = 8) = 'se'
AND (SELECT customDimensions.value FROM UNNEST(t.customDimensions) AS customDimensions WHERE customDimensions.index = 4) = 'soffadirekt'
AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20211001' AND '20211002'

)

SELECT
raw.event_action,
raw.orderId_bq,
raw.trx_id,
raw.page,
raw.hitnumber,

FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER(ORDER BY raw.hitnumber DESC) as RN,
raw.event_action,
raw.orderId_bq,
raw.trx_id,
raw.page,
raw.hitnumber

FROM raw) AS raw
```